# Django Rest Framework : How to add a custom field to the response of the GET request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and have just started building an API.

I've a model called **Shop**.
And I've two user different user types : **Customer** and **Supplier**.

1. I want to add a custom field **distance** to the response of the GET request **/shops/id/**, which represents the distance between the Customer that is submitted the request and the corresponding shop.
2. I think I cannot use *SerializerMethodField* since the value of the method is not only depend on the object itself.
3. I do not want to add this custom field for all GET requests, instead, I need to add it, when the user that is submitted the request is a **Customer**.

Considering constraints above, how should I add the custom field to the response of the request? What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: What else does the value depends on?

Comment: Value for distance depends on the location of the shop and the current location of the customer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `distance` [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), and there access the current user location using serializer's `context`. Then compute distance using current user location and shop's location.

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = (.., 'distance')

    def get_distance(self, obj):
        current_user = self.context['request'].user # access current user    
        user_location = current_user.location

        distance = <compute distance using obj.location and user_location>
        return distance
```

Comment: What about for both GET and POST? For POST it can be done by overriding create() method but what for GET?

Comment: @MahabuburRahamanMelon It should work for both the methods GET(retrieve) and POST(create).